# Android ListView Get row on button click

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a custom adapter class for a listview and I want to be able to access the content of a specific row by clicking a button on it. I tried to create a ViewHolder, but I get a NPE error when I try to click it.

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView camera;
    TextView players;
    TextView max_players;
    ImageView privata;
    Button Buton;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String variabile[] = getItem(position).split("\\s+");
    LayoutInflater linflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.camera = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.Nume);
        holder.players = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.players);
        holder.max_players = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.max_players);
        holder.privata = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.privata);
        holder.Buton = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.Buton);
        holder.camera.setText(variabile[0]);
        if (!variabile[1].equals("true")) {
            parola = false;
            holder.privata.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        holder.players.setText(variabile[2]);
        holder.max_players.setText(variabile[3]);
        room_id = variabile[4];
        nume = variabile[5];
        holder.Buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hash = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hash.put("name", nume);
                hash.put("room", room_id);
                if (intra) {
                    holder.Buton.setText("Iesi");
                    site = siteul + "/join";
                    intra = false;
                } else {
                    holder.Buton.setText("Intra");
                    site = siteul + "/leave";
                    intra = true;
                }
                new ATask().execute(site);
            }
        });
    return customView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the ViewHolder pattern, you should check if the convertView in null or has been created before, in the getView method, and after that use **setTag** and **getTag** methods. like this :

```
    if (convertView == null) 
    {
        LayoutInflater linflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.your_list_item_view, parent, false);
         viewHolder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById([the id]);
         .
         .
         .

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

Comment: Same thing, it seems that holder can't be linflater.inflate(...), because it should be a View.

Comment: Now it works, but I encountered another bug. The text is displayed correctly when I press a button, but no matter what button I press the global holder that I declared seems to be equal to the one for the last row. I'm trying to modify its contents from another function.

Comment: please add the new bug as a new question or edit your question, including the complete adapter implementation. so we can see what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the convertView is null so it is already has been visited or not then store the holder in tag Like

```
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater linflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        holder = linflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);....
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }//Common code
```

Comment: It says that holder can't be linflater.inflate(...), because it should be a View.